# I can't import modules from other folders

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I'm a bit new to the Python world. I'm using Python3 and having hard times with imports.

I was using PyCharm on Windows to write an application. Everything was working through the project until I switched to Linux and VS Code.

Now I can't use absolute imports for importing modules from other packages in the same project.

For example, I'd like to import from module cards all available  card types.

I tested the classes and everything is ok. I'm only getting this issue with the import stuff.

```
The project structure:

/
|-cards
    |-__init__.py
    |-card.py
    |-monster_card.py
    |-spell_card.py
    |-trap_card.py
    |-ritual_card.py
|-deck
    |-__init__py
    |-deck.py
|-system

# This is the code in __init__.py in cads package
from . trap_card import TrapCard
from . spell_card import SpellCard
from . ritual_card import RitualCard
from . monster_card import MonsterCard

__all__ = [TrapCard, SpellCard, RitualCard, MonsterCard]

# The following line, for example, does not work from inside another package
# I'm trying to import the modules in cards from deck
from cards import TrapCard, MonsterCard, SpellCard, RitualCard
```

When I try to import packages from another folders I get this error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "/root/git-repos/Yu-Gi-Oh/decks/deck.py", line 3, in 
>   from cards import TrapCard, MonsterCard, SpellCard, RitualCard
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cards'

[image: output]

Comment: do you mean `from . trap_card import TrapCard` or `from .trap_card import TrapCard`? There shouldn't be a space there if you mean to use a relative import.

Comment: I mean from .trap_card import TrapCard. Thank you. I fixed the relative importation, but still can't import the modules from other packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `import *`, python search the module from `sys.path`. You need to add your root dir into `sys.path` before call import stmt.

For your case, your root dir is `/`.

like:

```py
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

from cards import *
```

## other way

Add file `__init__.py` into your root dir for make it become a module. Then change `from cards import *` to `from .cards import *`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your solution worked. The problem here is that I don't get why it works. So now the 'cards' directory is added to sys.path, but is there any other simpler workaround for this issue? If not, guess I will need to create some sort of initializing file in order to add some directories to sys.path so making it all work. I was working on Windows environment and I hadn't go through this issue. Why? This is really confusing. I'd be more than grateful if you suggest something for reading. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. I tested both cases and they worked well.